# How do I select multiple columns having similar names

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table STMT_TABLE and it has columns- ID, NAME, COL1, COL2... COL99.
Now, I wish to select all the data in columns COL1 to COL99. 
Is there any replacement to (SELECT COL1, COL2... COL99 FROM tablename)?

Comment: 1. Get the column names by querying to schema. 2. Use them in your main query.

Comment: Other than `select*`, which I wouldn't recommend, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to specify all the 100 columns you can:

```
select column_name || ',' 
  from user_tab_columns 
 where table_name = 'TABLE_NAME_IN_UPPER_CASE'
 order by column_id
```

Then copy the output and past it into your query (Don't forget to remove the last comma):

```
select <PASTE_HERE_PREVIOUS_OUTPUT> 
  from <YOUR_TABLE_NAME>
```

But you can't use it in automatic mode, most of work you do with your own hands.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is one way to have column list created and then paste into 2nd select query. But I was hoping to get a way where I do not have to go through all the typing. Could this be done using some functions?

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL for this purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some kind of shell-scripting to solve this.

Here is one with powershell:

```
write-host -nonewline "select "
for ($i = 1; $i -le 98; $i++) {
    write-host -nonewline "COL$i, ";
}
write-host -nonewline "COL99";
write-host " from stmt_table where [...]"
```

I also use excel quite a bit for these kind of things, just create one column with the content "COL", and use the little square-thingy to copy it downwards. Then in the next column put 1 in the first row, 2 in the second, then 3, and use the little squarethingy to count. Column after this you put a comma and use the square-thingy. Then copy the whole thing to a text-editor, and use search-replace to remove and unwanted whitespace.